# vuejs retorna objeto student null ao tentar buscar estudante por id

Tags: vue.js, axios

Galera.
Eu estou com um problema agora.
Consegui resolver o erro 400,  mas agora eu não estou conseguindo retornar os dados do estudante pelo id dele.
Segue meu código abaixo:

```js
    data() {
        return {
            student: {
                name: "",
                lastname: "",
                telephone: ""
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async updateStudent() {
            const url = http://localhost:5000/students/student
            await axios.put(url, {
                name: this.student.name,
                lastname: this.student.lastname,
                telephone: this.student.telephone
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                this.student = response.data
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Erro!! " + error)     
            })
        },
        clean() {
            this.student.name = ""
            this.student.lastname = ""
            this.student.telephone = ""
        },
        created() {
            this.updateStudent()
            this.clean()
        }
    }
}
```

erros:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'student' of null"

found in

---> <FormSearchStudent>
       <SearchStudent> at src/pages/Students/SearchStudent.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1862
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917

TypeError: Cannot read property 'student' of null
    at submit (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"574491ba-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Students/FormSearchStudent.vue?vue&type=template&id=6e70ea68& (app.js:1502), <anonymous>:15:43)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179)
    at HTMLFormElement.original._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917)
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1862
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917
```

Comment: Geralmente ao utilizar o método put, deve-se passar um `id` na url. Exemplo: http://localhost:5000/students/student/1 <-- colocar um id aqui. Provavelmente o seu código está caindo no catch da função await. Por isso o erro.

Comment: tentei fazer por if so estava fazendo requisição post. Eu vou ter q fazer um ajuste na api e no front-end para resolver isso e depois volto a comentar se deu certo ou errado.

Comment: danizavtz o post eu arrumei. Fiz o ajuste recomendado por vc e funcionou.

Comment: Parabéns pela implementação.

Comment: denizavtz. Quanto a busca do usuário por id eu desisti de tentar implementar. vou implementar o delete q eh a mesma logica do put, tenho q passar o id na rota

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema específico, no seu bloco catch, você deve tratar os dados para você ter um retorno esperado.
Segue um exemplo de como seria o block catch:

```
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("Erro!! " + error)
    this.student: {
            name: "",
            lastname: "",
            telephone: ""
        }
    })
```

Após fazer este tratamento não deve mais ocorrer o erro `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'student' of null"`.

Porém gostaria de deixar claro que este não é a causa raiz do seu problema, apenas vai tratar para o objeto `student` não ser nulo, após ocorrer um erro na requisição.

Answer (score 0):

As vezes o axios muda a referência do "this" e então você não consegue acessá-lo para atribuir o valor de resposta para "student", para resolver isso uma possível solução seria deixar seu método updateStudent da seguinte maneira:

```
async updateStudent() {
            let self = this;
            const url = http://localhost:5000/students/student
            await axios.put(url, {
                name: this.student.name,
                lastname: this.student.lastname,
                telephone: this.student.telephone
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                self.student = response.data
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Erro!! " + error)     
            })
        };
```

Comment: estou com outro problema agora.

Comment: certo, qual o problema que precisa resolver?
caso queira, pode dar uma olhada nesse post que eu fiz sobre uma request GET com o axios, em breve farei mais https://programandosolucoes.wordpress.com/2020/07/25/consumindo-apis-com-o-axios-vuejs/

Answer (score 0):

Isso tem cara de problema de escopo (this), vc pode resolver fazendo assim:

```
methods: {
    async updateStudent() {
        try {
          const url = http://localhost:5000/students/student
          const { data } = await axios.put(url, {
            name: this.student.name,
            lastname: this.student.lastname,
            telephone: this.student.telephone
          })
          this.student = data
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
        
    },
    clean() {
        this.student.name = ""
        this.student.lastname = ""
        this.student.telephone = ""
    },
    created() {
        this.updateStudent()
        this.clean()
    }
}
```